What is the origin of Ariels?
Ariels are mentioned as lion-like men in Moab yet their origin is not discussed.
2 Samuel 23:20

And Benaiah the son of Jehoiada, the son of a valiant man, of
Kabzeel, who had done many acts, he slew two lionlike men of Moab: he
went down also and slew a lion in the midst of a pit in time of snow.


@Jason_ It's different enough  in that it asks their origin.

@DanFefferman I considered that and hesitated, but, "what is origin of the Ariels" is actually defined in the scope of the question at the bottom.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

The word ariel here is composed of the word for lion (ari) plus the word "el." This resembles a number of other names in the Bible, containing the suffix "el" (god). Several other people and places are also called Ariel. Because of this some translators of understand "Ariel" to be a proper name meaning "God's lion" or "lion-god," and the two men killed by Benaiah were his sons. These translations call them "sons of Ariel." Others consider that these "ariel" were "lion-like men," which makes sense in the context of this section of 2 Sam., which lists the exploits of David's "mighty men" in defeating various warriors and giants. Rashi specifically says that they were two "Moabite giants."
In terms of their origin, we know nothing other than that they came from Moab. If they were giants, they may have been Anakim (descended from Arba through Anak - Jos. 21:11). These people were driven out by Joshua, but apparently survived in Moab until the time of the judges (Judges 1:20). The Jewish Encyclopedia says they were:

A pre-Canaanite tribe, dwelling (according to Josh. xi. 21, 22, and
Judges i. 10, 20) in the hill country of Judah and in the Philistine
plain (Hebron, Debir, Anab, Gaza, Gath, Ashdod). Three clans are
mentioned: Sheshai, Ahiman, and Talmai (Judges, i. 10; Num. xiii. 22).

If the two men called ariel we not Anakites but Moabites, then their origin, biblically speaking, would be the incestuous relationship between Lot and one of his daughters. (Genesis 19:37) A third possibility is that these men were of mixed race/ethnicity, part Anakite and part Moabite.
